# iPhone - firing an event at a particular date

Tags: iphone

My app has certain events that have to fire at a certain date. When an event fires, it must show an alert and play a sound for a certain amount of time or play a mp3, for example.

How is this done? I as this because iOS will not allow an app to run on the background for much long and if I schedule a local notification I will not be allowed to play more than 30 seconds of sounds.

So, if this is not possible how do I see a lot of alarm clocks on the store that claim they will wake up you with music????

Can you guys point me the way?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local notification system is available to process these types of events in the background. Check out the [Local Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I mentioned that in my question, but local notifications doesn't explain why these apps on the store claim they will wake up with music. Are they in fact saying 30 seconds of music (that is the maximum allowed by local notifications) or there's another way of doing that?

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. I believe that they are, in fact, limited by the 30-second limit.

Comment: OK then, thanks. Just one question: when the app is on the foreground, but the screen dims out and iPhone goes to sleep, which state is the app entering? background?

Comment: When it sleeps, the UIApplicationDelegate's  - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application will be called. It isn't in the background, but it isn't active.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the apps that claim to wake up with music will play the music from the users iPod library using the iPod playing classes (see MPMusicPlayerController and related classes in the documentation), if the app is set up correctly then any music (or playlist) started via this method will continue to play once the app is quit - so the app would only need to run for a handful of seconds or so to set it all up and then would be able to quit.

Comment: This explains how the music starts playing when the app quits but that doesn't explain how a music plays when the alarm event fires in a date far in the future, that's what alarm clocks are all about.

Comment: I think between myself and Christopher A we've probably explained how the alarm clock app you mention most likely work.  Unfortunately this might not help you if your app needs to play sounds for longer than 30 seconds and they aren't from the users music/ipod library, unfortunately there's probably not much else that can be done if those are Apples rules.